# Determine the position of the mouse on an object

Tags: asp.net

I want to use an image of a map to allow the user to click on places where accidents have occurred. I have placed an image on my asp-page, but cannot find any events that will allow me to capture the click of a mouse-button, which in turn should return the x and y position within the image.
I am using ASP.NET with VB.NET.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: John, that is why I couldn't add any code, because I could not find the event to write any code. I am used to the .NET environment, but new to the web-development side of .NET.  I have this requirement working in the desktop environment, but can't get it to work on the web-page.  I am writing a Health and Safety application, where the user must be able to indicate on an image of a body where an injury has occurred. This is done by clicking on the image, and the co-ordinates are then stored in the database. As I mentioned, I have it working perfectly in VB.NET, just not in this environment.

Comment: Then you should familiarize yourself with HTML. Research "imagemap"

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are displaying an image in a pictureBox. Following is a C# solution which you could convert to VB.Net

```
    private int pointX;
    private int pointY;

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MouseEventArgs mouseEvent = (MouseEventArgs)e;
        pointX = mouseEvent.X;
        pointY = mouseEvent.Y;
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("X: {0} Y: {1}", pointX, pointY));
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        pointX = e.X;
        pointY = e.Y;
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that ASP.NET doesn't have a Click-event associated with the picture box :(